# Can't remove files in the printer spool

Tags: files, printing, delete

I can't remove files in the printer spool for some reason:

```
$ sudo ls /var/spool/cups
```

lists a bunch of files like 'c00083' etc.

```
$ sudo rm /var/spool/cups/*
rm: cannot remove '/var/spool/cups/*': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have permissions as a regular user to view the contents of the /var/spool/cups directory; `sudo ls` gave `ls` the permissions to view the contents, but your regular-user shell failed to read it when it tried to expand the `/var/spool/cups/*` wildcard, so it passed that string through verbatim to `rm`, which complained about that lack of a file named (precisely) `/var/spool/cups/*`.

Gather the actual filename(s) first, then pass them to `sudo rm`.

Comment: Ok, so how do I do that?

Comment: `sudo ls /var/spool/cups | sudo xargs rm`, but personally I prefer `sudo bash -c "rm /var/spool/cups/*"`.

Comment: Or use native `lp` commands such as `lprm -` ("to cancel all jobs")

Comment: @JeffSchaller That does not remove the files in the spool

Comment: Then I'd recommend Weijun Zhou's `sudo bash -c "rm /var/spool/cups/*"` alternative, or `sudo -s; rm /var/spool/cups/*; exit`